# How can i build this type of UI in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace

I tried creating this UI in gmail addon using google script but not able to get this layout. i saw another app has implemented this. Please see the attached image for more details ! (https://i.ibb.co/jwnrggS/image-2.png) Can someone help me with this?

```
function getRedirect(pageId,title){
var redirectform = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('redirectCallback')
    .setParameters({page:pageId.toString()});
var redirectButton = CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText(title)
   .setOnClickAction(redirectform);
  return redirectButton;
}
function redirectCallback(e){
  var pageId = parseInt(e.parameters.page);
   var newCard,redirectBtn;
   if(pageId == 1){
  redirectBtn = getRedirect(2,"Next");
   newCard = CardService.newCardBuilder()
                 .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
                                     .setTitle("Page2"))
                 .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
                       .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet()
                             .addButton(redirectBtn))).build()
   }
    var navigate = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(newCard);
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
                   .setNavigation(navigate).build()  
   }

  function buildAddOn() {
      var header = getHeaderSection();
      var body = getBody();
      var submitForm = CardService.newAction()
                              .setFunctionName('openLinkCallback');
       var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton()
                                 .setText('Open Google')
                              .setOnClickAction(submitForm);
       var redirectBtn = getRedirectBtn(1,"Next");
       var mainCard = CardService
        .newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
       .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(submitButton)))
       .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()             
       .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(redirectBtn)))
       .build();
   return mainCard;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, you should at least include an attempt of your own in the question.

Comment: I tried many ways, i am able to do this in first page of my gmail addon. I have implemented navigation Using [this](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/navigation). Stack of cards like this i am able to do in first page of my app but not able to implement in second as i can push only one card to card stack. Because of this i posted this question. @ross i have updated the question and added same code for first page. I wanted to implement the given example in second page.

Comment: What  does your layout look like?

Comment: @Cooper Please see the attached image for required layout.

Answer (score 2):

To build a custom card UI, you need to have a thorough look at the Google Card building architecture[1.](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/card-interfaces), [2.](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/interactions) and decide which features you want to implement in your card.

For example, the card in the image you attached, features a drowndown menu - [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input-type) is the documentation about how to to select DROPDOWN as the SelectionInput Type.

As for the search field - you can insert a [TextInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input) field and implement programatically a search function that checks if the user's input corresponds to an element of an array containing "channels" or "people".

The [Card Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/) overview provides you documentaton of a wide range of methods to customize your Card UI.